# [pygerrit2]HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url:

Tags: python, gerrit

I am using pygerrit2 to authenticate to my gerrit server and running into below error, the username and password are correct as I use the same to login manually from gerrit UI,why am I getting this error and how to fix it?

```
from pygerrit2 import GerritRestAPI, HTTPBasicAuth

auth = HTTPBasicAuth('username', 'password')
print auth
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://tech.company.com', auth=auth)
changes = rest.get("/changes/?q=owner:self%20status:open")
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get_related_changes.py", line 62, in <module>
    changes = rest.get("/changes/?q=owner:self%20status:open")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygerrit2/rest/__init__.py", line 156, in get
    decoded_response = _decode_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygerrit2/rest/__init__.py", line 51, in _decode_response
    response.raise_for_status()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 939, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://tech.company.com/a/changes/?q=owner:self%20status:open
```

Comment: Is your gerrit configured to use basic auth?

Comment: I believe older versions of gerrit default to HTTP Digest only, while current versions default to HTTP Basic but have a variety of different options for selecting which password to use, and by default it's not the same password you use in the GUI, it's the randomly-generated one used for git+https (which you can see in the GUI from your user settings page).

Comment: @abarnert - how to know if my gerrit is configured to use basic auth?

Comment: @user3508811 if the gerrit version is earlier than 2.14 then it most likely uses digest auth. Later versions use basic.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make sure you're using the correct auth type for your Gerrit version.  Versions prior to 2.14 use digest auth by default; 2.14 and later use basic.

Secondly, make sure you're using the correct password. It should be the one from the HTTP Password section of your user settings.

Answer (score 0):

It may be helpful, I solved a similar problem by reading the username and password from the configuration file.

Try:

```
# config.ini

[my_app]
USERNAME = enter_username
PASSWORD = enter_password
```

Install [configparser](https://pypi.org/project/configparser/) from Python 3.8 for Python 2.6+: `pip install configparser`.
See the great [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) for more details.

```py
from pygerrit2 import GerritRestAPI, HTTPBasicAuth
import configparser

config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')

my_user = config.get('my_app', 'USERNAME')
my_pass = config.get('my_app', 'PASSWORD')

auth = HTTPBasicAuth(my_user, my_pass)
print auth
rest = GerritRestAPI(url='https://tech.company.com', auth=auth)
changes = rest.get("/changes/?q=owner:self%20status:open")
```